# Applescript, having trouble with if and subprocesses of this script

Tags: macos, applescript, vpn, kill

Basically, I wrote a script to kill the network (wifi as of now, will try and figure out ethernet in a bit) when the vpn disconnects. I wanted to add a failsafe that also killed applications, but when I added this bit of code

```
if application "iTunes" is running then do shell script "killall iTunes"
            if application "uTorrent" is running then do shell script "killall uTorrent"
            if application "Transmission" is running then do shell script "killall Transmission"
            if application "Safari" is running then do shell script "killall Safari"
            if application "Google Chrome" is running then do shell script "killall 'Google Chrome'"
            if application "Palringo" is running then do shell script "killall Palringo"
```

to the script, I kept having trouble with running it. I'm honestly not sure how the ifs are supposed to be used in this situation.

**I want it to do the following**

```
- if myConnection is not null and 
- if vpn is not connected

- kill wifi 
- and also do the following "if statements":

if application "iTunes" is running then do shell script "killall iTunes"
if application "uTorrent" is running then do shell script "killall uTorrent"
if application "Transmission" is running then do shell script "killall Transmission"
if application "Safari" is running then do shell script "killall Safari"
if application "Google Chrome" is running then do shell script "killall 'Google Chrome'"
if application "Palringo" is running then do shell script "killall Palringo"
```

**b**ut I'm not really sure how to do that / everything I have done has failed. This is my code.****

```
on idle


tell application "System Events"
    tell current location of network preferences
        set myConnection to the service "BTGuard VPN"
        if myConnection is not null then
            if current configuration of myConnection is not connected then do shell script "/usr/sbin/networksetup -setairportpower en1 off"



                if application "iTunes" is running then do shell script "killall iTunes"
                if application "uTorrent" is running then do shell script "killall uTorrent"
                if application "Transmission" is running then do shell script "killall Transmission"
                if application "Safari" is running then do shell script "killall Safari"
                if application "Google Chrome" is running then do shell script "killall 'Google Chrome'"
                if application "Palringo" is running then do shell script "killall Palringo"
        end if
    end tell
    return 0
end tell
end idle
```

**That's what's failing. Everything I have tried has something wrong. And correction/guidance/advice/help would be GREATLY appreciated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would move the "do shell script" lines outside of the "system events" tell block of code. Something like this would work...

```
on idle
    set vpnIsDisconnected to false
    tell application "System Events"
        tell current location of network preferences
            set myConnection to the service "BTGuard VPN"
            if myConnection is not null then
                if current configuration of myConnection is not connected then set vpnIsDisconnected to true
            end if
        end tell
    end tell

    if vpnIsDisconnected then
        do shell script "/usr/sbin/networksetup -setairportpower en1 off"
        if application "iTunes" is running then do shell script "killall iTunes"
        if application "uTorrent" is running then do shell script "killall uTorrent"
        if application "Transmission" is running then do shell script "killall Transmission"
        if application "Safari" is running then do shell script "killall Safari"
        if application "Google Chrome" is running then do shell script "killall 'Google Chrome'"
        if application "Palringo" is running then do shell script "killall Palringo"
    end if

    return 0
end idle
```

Comment: Oh okay. I see how that works and everything. Is there any reason the way I had it was wrong (speaking of the syntaX)?

Comment: also, does that return cover the entire script. Because when I ran it idle, it failed to do anything when the vpn disconnected.

Comment: The reason to separate the code is because it's inefficient to tell the Terminal to perform "do shell script" statements. The return tells the "on idle" handler how often to perform itself. So really 0 seconds doesn't make sense. When you use 0 then applescript will use a default value of 30 seconds. You probably want to change that to something more reasonable. I can't vouch for your code so I can't say why it didn't work... I was just helping with your question about the if statement...although maybe it's because of the "30 second" stuff I just explained... maybe you didn't wait long enough.

Comment: Regarding your original syntax, it is wrong. You would want all of your "if application" code inside the "if current configuration" statement. So you would need to place the "do shell script" portion of that if statement on the next line and put an "end if" after the last "if application" line.

Comment: I meant to say... The reason to separate the code is because it's inefficient to tell System Events to perform "do shell script" statements. The "do shell script" command is an applescript command, not a system events command so there's no reason to put that code inside the system events tell block of code. 1) it's inefficient and 2) it could cause some unexpected errors because system events doesn't know that command.

Comment: I ocasionally get a message saying "connection invalid", but nothing happens. Does this mean the VPN temporarily leaks? But it still disconnects/kills wifi when the vpn fails.

Comment: I really don't know. I don't have a VPN to test with. My guess is there's some quirkiness getting the "current configuration". You may be able to avoid those errors by using a try block around that line of code so at least you ignore that line of code when that error appears.